# Angular Material Snackbar not opening when called inside of error handling method

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-httpclient, snackbar

I have service level error handling for my API requests. This works great except I want to be able to notify users that something went wrong on the UI other than just the console messages. I figured Material Snackbars would be great for this.

After doing some research it looks like the Angular HttpClient runs outside of the zone, so I wrapped my snackbar.open() method like so to solve the issue:

```
  //POST METHOD
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  addNewCategory(category: CreateCategory): Observable<CreateCategory> {
    return this.http
    .post<CreateCategory>(this.url + "/create", category)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  //ERROR HANDLING METHOD
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log("Client Side Error: ", errorResponse.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Server Side Error: ", errorResponse);
      this.openSnackbar("Category Not Added.");
    }

    return throwError("There is an issue with the call.);
  }

  //SNACK BAR METHOD
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  openSnackbar(snackMessage: string) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this._snackBar.open(snackMessage, "Close", {
        duration: 7000
      });
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately, this still yields the same results. Supposedly the fix above did work at one point, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372915/angular-5-material-snackbar-is-not-showing-correctly-for-custom-errorhandling-on).

I have also tried doing the error handling in the component, which is not correct practice from what I understand, but I still got the same results even with the zone fix. Here is the error message I get in the console when the snackbar tries to fire:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: this.openSnackbar is not a function
at CatchSubscriber.push../src/app/services/people-category.service.ts.PeopleCategoryService.handleError [as selector] (people-category.service.ts:93)
at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:83)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:61)
at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:83)
at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:61)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:13)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:18)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:61)
at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
```

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Use this syntax `.pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));` or define the callback as an arrow function: `private handleError = (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan This works and was just what I was looking for. I am not a huge javascript guy so I didn't exactly know what to search for when I was getting this issue. I appreciate you linking this post, it has helped me understand what was going on much better.